# Java random number generator not working

Tags: java, android, random

My random number generator is not working and I don't understand it. I am new to android programming and I can not figure out this peace of code. I have tried it several ways and it does not work properly. Please help me out, I am new please do not flame me.

Examples: of actual code production

First Set of trees spawned
1011010110

Second set of trees spawned within same game
100001111110011

```
 import java.util.Random;
 import android.util.Log;

 public class Tree {
 public Tree(int addition) {

    spawn = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
 }
```

I have also have tried.

```
private Random random = new Random();
public Tree(int addition) {

    int randomNum = random.nextInt(2);
    spawn = randomNum;
}
```

Thanks for looking this over.

Steve

Comment: what's it not doing / doing wrong?

Comment: There is no difference between your second and third code snippets; did you mean to type something else?  Anyway, you haven't given us enough information; I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code, and you haven't told us what the incorrect output is and what you're expecting.

Comment: For the middle and last example, Random#nextInt returns a value between 0(inclusive) and the passed in parameter(exclusive) so add 1 to your result and you'll get 121211122221...

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry I was using 1 and 2 as example numbers I really do want 1 and 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which code you're referring to producing those outputs but this line of code will return either 0 or 1...

```
spawn = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
```

something like this would return a number between 0 and 9

```
spawn = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
```

This happens because the Math.random() function `Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.` -- per [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29)

*EDIT -
It looks like the output is what you'd expect although the second set has some suspicious looking repetition... If you're outputting both of these

```
private Random random = new Random();
public Tree(int addition) {

    int randomNum = random.nextInt(2); // this will be 0 or 1
    spawn = randomNum;                 // this will NOT BE RANDOM
}
```

I think this is where you're seeing the repetition in your second tree. To fix this you can just remove the `spawn` variable because all you're doing is reassigning it in this case.

Comment: No, it will not return "either 1 or 2".

Comment: sorry, I was using 1 and 2 as examples. I do really want to produce 0 and 1.

Comment: So what output are you actually getting?

Comment: First Set of trees spawned
1011010110

Second set of trees spawned within same game
100001111110011

Comment: see the edit to my answer, if you're outputting both randomNum and spawn in that section then that will explain your problem

Answer (score 0):

nextInt(int n)

Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

reference is here :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

so when you call random.nextint(2), you will get either 0 or 1.

you may add some value or change the parameter to fit your needs.

Comment: Can you please look at my game again. I actually used 1 and 2 as an example. I actully wanted 1 and 0. I also added a actually game produced code to show you what is happening

Comment: I don't see your point, so I think nextInt(2) will work for you